# Set my ASP.NET MVC 3 project automatically perceive which Language is running

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a internationalized project(working on either Chinese or English), i switch the language circumstance by commenting out `<add key="Localization" value="zh-CN"/>` in web.config file.

There's a small issue keeps bugging me, in some pages there are some "Register" or "Save"-buttons of which imgurl are defined in a css file. However, i intend to switch the imgurl by javascript since there are two images in two diff language (img with Chinese "Register" and "Save").

So far, i m stucking in no man's land. Dont have no clue. How could i set my project automatically to detect which Language version is running? Can Javascript do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first we need is add new routes for make for example ur main language by default

```
context.MapRoute(
                name: "lang",
                url: "{lang}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints : new { lang = @"zh|en" },
                namespaces: new[] { "NamespaceToControllers" }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                name : "default",
                url : "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults : new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, lang = "zh" },
                namespaces : new [] { "NamespaceToControllers" }
            );
```

Second part - we must modified DefaultController to change cultureInfo and remove it in configure file BaseController

```
public class DefaultController : BaseController
    {
        public string CurrentLangCode { get; protected set; }

        public Language CurrentLang { get; protected set; }

        protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
            {
                HostName = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority;
            }

            if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] != null && requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] as string != "null")
            {
                CurrentLangCode = requestContext.RouteData.Values["lang"] as string;

                var ci = new CultureInfo(CurrentLangCode);
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);
            }
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
        }
    } 

public class BaseController {

     protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            if (requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url != null)
            {
                HostName = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Authority;
            }
            base.Initialize(requestContext);
        }
}
```

To check this just write after main url **/en** 
**3th part**

we must change static content like buttons and we need to add new Asp.net folder like so -**App.LocalResourses** and create there new files - **GlobalRes.resx** and **GlobalRes.en.resx**

In this files add strings by current language of buttons or something static

After all we need change properties of .resx files:

```
Build Action: Embedded Resource
Custom Tool: PublicResXFileCodeGenerator
```

And we must add new namespaces to web.config

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="urAppNamespace.Helper" />
        <add namespace="urAppNamespace.Tools" />
        <add namespace="urAppNamespace.App_LocalResources" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

And this is examples implement this logic

```
<li><span class="login">@GlobalRes.Enter</span></li>
<li>@Html.ActionLink(GlobalRes.Register, "Register", "User")</li>
```